Where is the best place to source game-fi devs?
Greetings everyone from GUAP im DEGEN aka Lee
I'm just wondering best places to get help with developing a game on the Solana network. It is a card game and the cards will be nfts which will be minted in packs (if possible) before game is ready for beta testing. I'm looking help from Solana Devs or any people who outsource their abilities. The game is basically top trumps only you can bet or play for free or play to give which will put pot winnings into a multisig charity wallet.
Are there places I/we can go looking for help? We have a dev who thinks he can build the game to its basic form but we might need additional help/funds to achieve this. I am currently in talks with a third-party company that builds games on all platforms but I have a feeling cost wise outsourcing to a studio will be more costly than keeping it within solana ecosystem devs or devs in crypto in general.
We are a fair launched community-run project we have a big enough marketing wallet 10% of guap and 20 sol of our own and half of the guap in marketing wallet was actually bought up by core team memebers and put into marketing wallet.
We are a meme but we want the chance to build something different and have a quick paced, addictive card game easy accessible to people. We are also looking to build an ecosystem and have a reward token for staking GUAP and if you hold your rewards it will offer powerups in the game which is a nice incentive to hold your rewards.
If the card game is successful season one is memes, we will do more seasons but also think about building different types of games and then having a game lobby in the future.
Can anyone point me in the right direction for maybe gamefi devs or grants. Solana Foundation did provide us some links and told us to come back when we have a MVP which we dont yet have but I thought I would ask in here. While it's bearish we thought it's best time to build the game!
We are just about to release our white paper, NFTS are nearly completed so we will be starting with mint first, which could also be another source of funds to help with the game, but we want the majority of it to go into marketing wallet.
Anyways if you can help or know someone please reach out to me on our telegram (i'm degen on tg) - guap_sol or on this post.
